# how to get top 300 rows for each group in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have table like this

```
dlrecipientid  dlrecipientlistid
1                  1
2                  1
..                 ..
999                1
1000               1
1001               2
1002               2
..                 ..
1999               2
2000               2
```

How can query and get top 300 rows `dlrecipientlistid`

eample

```
dlrecipientid  dlrecipientlistid
1                  1
2                  1
..                 ..
299                1
300                1
1001               2
1002               2
..                 ..
1299               2
1300               2
```

I need query in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with self joining in following way :

```
  SELECT tbl1.* FROM your_table AS tbl1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN your_table AS tbl2 
    ON (tbl1.dlrecipientlistid= tbl2.dlrecipientlistid 
        AND tbl1.dlrecipientid > tbl2.dlrecipientid)
  GROUP BY tbl1.dlrecipientid  
  HAVING COUNT(*) < 300
  ORDER BY tbl1.dlrecipientid,tbl1.dlrecipientlistid DESC;
```

I've updated query and well tested in [**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/98068/27)

Comment: SELECT tbl1.* FROM hm_distributionlistsrecipients AS tbl1
 LEFT JOIN hm_distributionlistsrecipients AS tbl2 
    ON tbl1.distributionlistrecipientlistid= tbl2.distributionlistrecipientlistid 
 GROUP BY tbl1.distributionlistrecipientid
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 300  
ORDER BY tbl1.`distributionlistrecipientlistid` ASC

Comment: @James123 : I've updated query and tested well. Please go with updated query

Answer (score 0):

```
(
 select *
 from mytable 
 where `group` = 1
  LIMIT 300
 )
UNION ALL
(
select *
from mytable 
where `group` = 2
LIMIT 300
```

)

Comment: dlrecipientlistid not table

Comment: I have 100 dlrecipientlistid in the table. I just gave sample

Answer (score 0):

Seems to need use variable:

```
select
    dlrecipientlistid,
    dlrecipientid,
    @rowno := case when @grp = dlrecipientlistid then @rowno + 1 else 1 end as rowno,
    @grp := dlrecipientlistid
from yourtable
cross join (select @rowno := 0, @grp := null) t
order by dlrecipientlistid, dlrecipientid
having rowno <= 300
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

`select * from <table_name> limit 300;`